# Login Mutation for Graphql not finding user

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jwt, schema, graphql

I am trying to create an authentication service with graphql and mongodb. I have created my login mutation which takes in the email and password. I am using bcrypt to hash and unhash the passwords.

It's not a import issue or a mongodb issue it's graphql.

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        username: {type: GraphQLString},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        password: {type: GraphQLString},
        institution: {
            type: InstitutionType,
            resolve(parent, args){
                return Institution.findById(parent.institutionId)
            }
        }
    })
});
```

```
login:{
                type:GraphQLString,
                args:{
                    email: {type: GraphQLString},
                    password: {type: GraphQLString}
                },
                resolve: async (parent, { email, password }, { models, SECRET }) => {
                    const user = await models.User.findOne({ where: { email } });
                    if (!user) {
                      throw new Error('No user with that email');
                    }

                    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
                    if (!valid) {
                      throw new Error('Incorrect password');
                    }

                    const token = jwt.sign(
                      {
                        user: _.pick(user, ['id', 'username']),
                      },
                      SECRET,
                      {
                        expiresIn: '1y',
                      },
                    );

                    return token;
                  },
                },
              }});
```

It should return a jwt token which can later be used for authentication. First I was running this in the graphiql in my browser:

```
mutation{
  login(email: "ammarthayani@gmail.com", password:"password"){
  }
}
```

and it was giving me this in the console : "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found

Then I tried:

```
mutation{
  login(email: "ammarthayani@gmail.com", password:"password"){
    username
  }
}
```

which gave me: Field \"login\" must not have a selection since type \"String\" has no subfields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type for the `login` field on your `Mutation` type is `GraphQLString`, which is a scalar. Since scalars are leaf nodes, they do not have a selection set (i.e. other "child" fields). [From the spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Leaf-Field-Selections):

> If selectionType is a scalar or enum:
>
> - The subselection set of that selection must be empty
>
> If selectionType is an interface, union, or object
>
> - The subselection set of that selection must NOT BE empty

Curly brackets are used to indicate a selection set, so they should not be used when the return type for a field is a scalar or an enum. Your query needs to simple be:

```
mutation {
  login(email: "ammarthayani@gmail.com", password:"password")
}
```

Comment: When I run this it returns:Cannot read property User of undefined

Comment: `models` is presumably undefined, since you reference that in the first line of your resolver, but hard to know for sure without seeing the complete code and the full stack trace

Comment: I used models because it said that in the tutorial I was trying to follow. What is that supposed to mean and how can I do a full stack trace? Sorry I’m new to graphql

Comment: The example you're following is assuming you're injected `models` in your context. How you do that depends on what you're using on the backend to server the GraphQL endpoint. You should be able to skip that step for now and just import your models directly in your module, though. Try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Otherwise, I imagine your tutorial should cover how to configure the context for your GraphQL endpoint.

Comment: The mongoose models that I have created I have in a separate folder and I am importing them seperatly.

Comment: I just need the login mutation to work because everything so far is working. If you need any other code to solve this problem I can post it

Comment: So then don't worry about pulling `models` out of context -- just import the User mongoose model directly and call `User.findOne` instead of `models.Users.findOne`

Comment: I did that and now it is saying that there is no user with that email even though I already have the user made

Comment: I’m using the MongoDb online database service. I think it’s called Atlas. I don’t know if that has to do with anything

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue unrelated to your original question. If this answer solved your original issue, I would mark it as accepted and if you are still having the latter problem, you can post another question with all relevant details.

Comment: No it didn’t because the login mutation when I run it says that the user could not be found

Comment: I’m still not able to get a confirmation that the user was logged in

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the rest of your resolver code. If a user can't be found with that email, then it's likely that the user isn't being created correctly in the first place. It's impossible to debug that with the code you've provided, though. And again, that's unrelated to the syntax error you were seeing, which was your original issue. Feel free to open a new question and provide additional details there. SO questions themselves should be limited to one question per post.

Comment: I ended up fixing the login code and now it works as intended. Thank you so much saved me hours of frustration.